# Can't pass in configuration section to IServiceCollection.Configure<T>() anymore

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a console application and want to configure my Options by mapping the configuration from the `appsettings.json` file to a custom class. Packages I installed so far

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration v5.0.0
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection v5.0.1
- Microsoft.Extensions.Options v5.0.0

Given this sample class

```
public class MyOptions
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

and this configuration

```
{
    "myOptions": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to map it with this code

```
public void ConfigureOptions(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    IConfiguration configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
    IConfigurationSection myConfigurationSection = configuration.GetSection("MyOptions");
    serviceCollection.Configure<MyOptions>(myConfigurationSection);
}
```

Unfortunately this is invalid syntax. It is not possible to pass in the section to the `Configure` method anymore.

> Argument type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Action<MyApp.MyOptions>'

This confuses me since there is a similar example in the docs

[image]

Does someone know if I'm missing something?

Comment: Did you intend to call `Configure<TOptions>(IServiceCollection, IConfiguration)`? You're getting the error because `IServiceCollection` doesn't define a `Configure` method that accepts an `IConfigurationSection`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are missing the [`Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/) package.